# Qt Android error: Diffie-Hellman parameters are not valid

Tags: android, qt, ssl, diffie-hellman

In a Qt app I make a GET request to https://www.google.es using QNetworkRequest. In Linux desktop this works fine, I get the page's content, but when I run it in my Android device I get the following error in my QNetworkReply:

> Diffie-Hellman parameters are not valid

Qt version is 5.8, device is Samsung S6 running Android 6.0.1. The problem happens with any https URL.

Anyone knows the meaning of this message? I've been googling for two hours with no result... Thanks a lot!!

Update: I'm not using any custom SSL configuration, just a QNetworkAccessManager and a QNetworkRequest. Calling QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().diffieHellmanParameters().error() returns 2 (UnsafeParametersError) and QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().diffieHellmanParameters().isValid() returns false.

Comment: Do you set your custom QSslConfiguration on a request object? If not, could you, please, try to check default QSslConfiguration? What's the value of QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().diffieHellmanParameters().error() ? or QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration().diffieHellmanParameters().isValid() ?

Comment: The error() method returns 2 (UnsafeParametersError) and isValid() returns false. It seems that the default SSL configuration in Android is somehow invalid (in Linux desktop the call succeeds). Any way to fix this?